# Python Note script with dictionary throwing error

Tags: python, string, dictionary, for-loop

python 2.7.9 so i wanted to make a script to run constantly where i can take notes on names and characteristics but i don't know why its throwing this error.  eventually i would like it to be exported to a file so it can save the inputted information.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PythonFiles\Dictionary.py", line 18, in 
key = input("Enter a player name: ")

File "", line 1, in 
Name Error: name 'bob' is not defined

```
basket = {}
print("""
Note Program:
___________
1: Add Item
2: Remove Item
3: View
0: Exit Program

""")

option = int(input("Enter an Option: "))

while option != 0:
if option == 1:
    key = input("Enter a player name: ")

    if key in basket:
        print("Name Found!...")
        value = input("adding notes: ")
        basket[key] += value

    else:
        value = input("Notes: ")
        basket[key] = value

elif option == 2:
    key = input("Enter a player name: ")
    del(basket[key])

elif option == 3:
    for key in basket:
        print(key,":",basket[key])

elif option !=0:
    print("please enter a valid option")

option = str(input("\n\nEnter an option: "))

else:
    print("Note Program Closed.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, as input is trying to `eval()` which is causing the exception.

- `raw_input()` takes the input and passes it back as a string.
- `input()` will actually run as `eval(raw_input())`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification... never delved into dictionaries like this before.